# NSIS unicode build for linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unicode, installation, nsis

I have NSIS software installed on my Ubuntu server. Recently, with my NSIS script, I can successfully build setup files for my windows software. The problem lie in situation when end user has non ANSI characters for username, so I need unicode installer. Installation process is always in English language, but  some installation paths depending to username can be non ANSI characters. On NSIS official page there is already unicode version of nsis.exe, but i didn't find version for Linux.

One solution is to use wine program, but I'm looking for some other solution without wine.

How can i resolve this? Any advice is welcome. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean unicode version of **makensis.exe** instead of nsis.exe?

makensis.exe is command line compiler for NSIS scripts while nsis.exe is simple application showing help, manual and other docs.

There is also makensisW.exe which is simple GUI interface for makensis.exe.

All of them are present in latest version of NSIS (3.0a1)

Since NSIS 3.0 there is new directive **Unicode** true|false. Put it in your script to generate full Unicode|Ansi installers.

Comment: Yes, I mean Unicode version of makensis.exe but under Linux distribution. Hm, I didn't know that 3.0 has Unicode support. Thank you for answer, I will try very soon.

Comment: Yes, solution with WINE it's OK for now. I didn't try WINE + 3.0a, because I already have solution with WINE and NSIS Unicode from [link](http://www.scratchpaper.com/announcements/2465released) which working good.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed 3.0b2 has unicode support on *nix (tested on Fedora 22).

Just add `Unicode true` to your nsi script.

```
Processing script file: "grouptest-utf8.nsi" (UTF8)

Processed 1 file, writing output (x86-unicode):

Output:     "grouptest.exe"
Install: 3 pages (192 bytes), 11 sections (45320 bytes), 192 instructions (5376 bytes), 449 strings (5116 bytes), 1 language table (282 bytes).

Using zlib compression.

EXE header size:               52224 / 37888 bytes
Install code:                   2810 / 34198 bytes
Install data:                      0 / 0 bytes
CRC (0x13123953):                  4 / 4 bytes

Total size:                    55038 / 72090 bytes (76.3%)
```